# Given an address, how can I get the congressional district?

Tags: geolocation, geocoding

Is there a library or service that returns the US federal congressional district given a US address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on [govtrack.us](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/members/map). I am not sure if there is a code framework for this, but you could probably write one from this information.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no longer an option because govtrack.us is being deprecated.  Sadly, ProPublica, its replacement, does not support this.  I have not been able to find an alternative yet.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure - I work for a company that also provides congressional district data - smartystreets.com

Keep in mind that this information changes often and I have been looking for the last 4.5 years and haven't yet pinpointed an actual, absolutely reliable source for this data.  All of the companies I have looked at, including mine, say that their source is the US Postal Service but no one in the US Postal Service has been willing to tell me how frequently the data is updated within their system and what their source might be.  So, just be aware.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the creators of Geocodio and we had this problem ourselves. So we made it part of our geolocation tools!

You can use the Geocodio API or spreadsheet upload to look up Congressional districts, Representative/Senator contact information, etc. Docs: https://www.geocod.io/docs/#congressional-districts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sunlight Foundation Congress API, which is free to use.  Go to: http://tryit.sunlightfoundation.com/congress You can determine congressional district by zipcode (not completely reliable since zipcodes can traverse multiple districts) or by latitude/longitude.  Just use Google geocoding to retrieve lat/lng from your address, and then you can look up the congressional district.

Comment: The Sunlight Foundation API no longer exists.

Comment: Looks like the project has been taken over by another organization: ProPublica. https://www.propublica.org/nerds/item/sunlight-labs-takeover-update. I am sure it works similiarly.

Comment: @DavidP: Unfortunately it doesn't. There is no location based search. https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/sunlight/.

Answer (score 0):

The [whoismyrepresentative.com/api](http://whoismyrepresentative.com/api) site can translate a zipcode into a congressional district. You can do a call with the url below, replacing 10038 with your zipcode.

http://whoismyrepresentative.com/getall_mems.php?zip=10038&output=json

Hope that helps!

**Also note that the sunlightfoundation site returns a 404 error and govtrack.us does not have an api for searching for congressional districts.